# etherscan request API limit

Tags: ether, etherscan, external-api, exchange-api

i want to know the limit request on etherscan API with API key, and limit if we go on paid service. thanks in advance.

Comment: You should rather contact them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of requests per second is limited to 5 request per second. There is not paid service yet.

> The Etherscan Ethereum Developer APIs are provided as a community
>   service and without warranty, so please just use what you need and no
>   more. They support both GET/POST requests and a rate limit of 5
>   requests/sec.
>
> To use the API service please create a FREE Api-Key Token from within
>   the ClientPortal->MyApiKey area which you can then use with all your
>   api requests. Either a link back or mention that your app is "Powered
>   by Etherscan.io APIs" would be appreciated.

[source](https://etherscan.io/apis)

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks, Jaime. what do you think about blockcypher API, or Infura

Comment: As far as I know infura doesn't have limits [source](https://github.com/INFURA/infura/issues/58). I found etherscan very useful and simple, I created a wrapper for python that you can find [here](https://github.com/jfdelgad/etherscanAPI). I didn't know about blockcypher until now, I took a quick look at it and it looks amazing, thanks for that. If this answered your question please accept the answer.

Comment: thanks again Jaime, just gave a good insight about infura and etherscan.

Comment: in first infura hasn't limit but it has limits now. limit is 100K req/day for free users. blockcypher has limit too. blockcypher has 3 req/sec and 200 req/hr limits.